# MuleSoft WebServiceComsumer pass Header

Tags: mule

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:WS_CONFIG_AX">
<soapenv:Header>
    <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
        <urn:userName>USERNAME</urn:userName>
        <urn:password>PASSWORD</urn:password>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <urn:authentication/>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <urn:locale/>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <urn:timeZone/>
    </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <urn:GetList_Operation_1>
        <urn:Qualification>'TYPE' = "Service Request"</urn:Qualification>
        <urn:startRecord>0</urn:startRecord>
        <urn:maxLimit>1</urn:maxLimit>
    </urn:GetList_Operation_1>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Using WebServiceConsumer I have to pass the username and password. I am not sure which to send. Can I use transform message or have to use a different method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a property named soap.AuthenticationInfo before constructing the payload and pass it to the wsconsumer.

See below: Here the payload should be constructed as the object AuthenticationInfo.

```
<set-property propertyName="soap.AuthenticationInfo" value="#[payload]"         doc:name="Property" />
```

After this construct your soap body (using dataweave or something) and pass it to the wsconsumer.

Check the section Adding custom headers in the below link:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/web-service-consumer